# Kernel module not loaded at boot, but fine afterwards via "modprobe"

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel

I have installed the latest Nvidia kernel driver on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, but after rebooting `nvidia-smi` could not communicate with the GPU. So I had to manually `modprobe nvidia` in order to load the module and make `nvidia-smi` and alike running.

But I want the system to automatically load that new kernel module when booting, so I added the new line "nvidia" to the file `/etc/modules` and rebooted. But still, the Nvidia module has not been loaded automatically.

I can, however, manually load that module via `modprobe` again. So the kernel module works, it's just not being loaded automatically at boot. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
$nvidia.modeset=1
```

to the line that contains `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="xx xxx nvidia.modeset=1"` in the `/etc/default/grub` file and then you should update the boot loader config by using

```
sudo update-grub
```

in void linux  or

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

so that parameter will be passed to the kernel on every boot by the boot loader.